# MIPS accepting blank input

Tags: arrays, input, try-catch, byte, mips

I have a function in MIPS that collects user input and puts it into an array of integers. How do I not crash on blank input? Is there some sort of catch that I am unaware of?

Obviously some test has to be performed in the loop, but how can I know what is being input if it is not an integer. The value 5 in the $v0 register ensures that only integers will be collected.

Here is the function:

```
####################################################################################
# Gather Numbers
# The collection loop in order for the user to input numbers, all integers are
# accepted, and blank inputs.
# a0 = the base address of the array.
####################################################################################
gather_numbers:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $a0, 0($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)
sw $s1, 8($sp)
sw $t1, 12($sp)

move $s0, $a0 #the address of the array
lw $s1, size # load the size
li $t1, 0 # so it enters the loop

start_gather_numbers: beq $t1, 9999, exit_gather_numbers
              li $v0, 5 # read the integer
              syscall
              sw $v0, 0($s0)
              move $t1, $v0 # put the value into t1 to be tested
              addi $s0, $s0, 4 #increment the address
              addi $s1, $s1, 1 # increment the size
              j start_gather_numbers
exit_gather_numbers:  addi $s1, $s1, -1 # fix the size
                  sw $s1, size # store the size
              lw $a0, 0($sp) # pop the stack
              lw $s0, 4($sp)
              lw $s1, 8($sp)
              lw $t1, 12($sp)
              addi $sp, $sp, 12
              jr $ra
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be worth the trouble to read a string and convert it to an integer? That would allow you to generate your own error on invalid input. Hopefully someone has an easier answer, but that's my default in any language - because I just don't trust black-box input routines.

Comment: What simulator are you using? `spim`? `MARS`?

Comment: @RobertB I thought of that but figured there had to be an easier way.

Comment: Unless the `read_int` syscall accepts blank input (what would it return in `$v0` in that case?), I don't see how you can avoid using `read_string` and then parsing that string.

Comment: Is there a pseudo instruction for that? I have heard people mention atoi?

Comment: @TrevorHutto There's definitely not an `atoi` pseudo-op. For my class project, our team had to roll our own atoi and itoa routines.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use exception handlers. When an exception is thrown, the program immediately jumps to a different address. You can put custom instructions at the specific address for the complier to follow. It helps a program die gracefully, or continue by correcting the input.

Check out this link http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/MarsExceptions.html